# read the json file to output to an highcharts

Tags: json, angularjs, highcharts

I came to read the json file to output to an highcharts.

I have a highcharts areagraph whose values are received from json whose format is as follows:

```
scope.jsondata = [
    {
        "Name": "A",
        "Categories": "03.01",
        "Locate": "1",
        "Value": 30
    },
    {
        "Name": "A",
        "Categories": "03.02",
        "Locate": "1",
        "Value": 50
    },
    {
        "Name": "A",
        "Categories": "03.03",
        "Locate": "1",
        "Value": 60
    },
    {
        "Name": "A",
        "Categories": "03.04",
        "Locate": "1",
        "Value": 40
    },
    {
        "Name": "A",
        "Categories": "03.05",
        "Locate": "1",
        "Value": 70
    }
];
```

How can I embed those values for my jsondata in angularJS?

```
scope.render = function (data) {
    var target = element.find('#detail-usage-chart'),
        firstDate = {
            name: scope.jsondata.Name,
            data:  scope.jsondata.Vaule,
            color: '#f48d7f',
            type: 'area'
        },
        tempOption = {
            data: [10, 13, 17, 8, 11, 5, 11, 13 ,16, 18, 20, 13, 16, 21, 19],
            type: 'spline',
            yAxis: 1
        }
};
```

Please provide a suitable way to embed the data from json.

Comment: what do you mean by embedding?

Comment: I tried to put the value of the data to json data for firstDate.

Comment: since `scope.jsondata` is an array you need to pass an index to get the object at the respective position, e.g. `name: scope.jsondata[0].Name`

Comment: I have a data element that has the same in the json, As with tempOption.data below to put it into the data of firstdate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Area chart is expecting a name and an array contaning values in its series:
[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/area-basic/)

So all you have to do is just a quick function in order to prepare your data that way. For example:

```
var scope.readyValues = [];
for(var i=0;i<scope.jsondata.length;i++)
{
    scope.readyValues.push(scope.jsondata[i].Value);    
}
```

Next, just configure the series this way:

```
// .....chart options
series: [{
            name: scope.jsondata[0].Name,
            data: scope.readyValues
        }
```

If you have multiple Names in your scope.jsondata then you can use jquery map function or you can make an array for each name.
And since you're using angular I recommend you use [Highcharts-ng](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng) it's easier ;)

Comment: If the json-file

{
"Name": "B",
"Categories": "03.05",
"Locate": "2",
"Value": 70
}

Add this content doeseo

secondDate = {
                             name: scope.jsondata [1] .Name
                         }
When you try to display a B in the second good thing to do?

Comment: What ???? when you have a B name in the data you may use the $.map() function to map As together and Bs together.

Comment: I means, the json-file is{
         "Name": "A",
         "Categories": "03.05",
         "Locate": "1",
         "Value": 70
     },{
         "Name": "B",
         "Categories": "03.05",
         "Locate": "2",
         "Value": 70
     }. In this case, I use $.map()?

Comment: Yes you can use map if you have like A, B, ..., Z. Here's a plunker showing how to, with simply As: http://plnkr.co/edit/NfrBfERVGqgGcRGl8X5k?p=preview

Comment: Can I tell you how to use the map?

Comment: give me an example of your data here: http://pastebin.com/ I will make a plunker and don't forget to vote my answer please

Comment: Here: http://plnkr.co/edit/NfrBfERVGqgGcRGl8X5k?p=preview
It's not that pretty, you have to change to chart options to make it look nice, but this way you can have as many names as you want ;)

Comment: Last question, When I try to save the output to each Data separately for each field, (A in the Name, Value is in firstdate {}), then
firstDate = {
  name: cat.name,
  data: cat.value,
  type: 'area'
},

This process happens from here?

Comment: Yes you can add an object firstDate and inside it you can add properties like that, but it won't show in highcharts ;)

Comment: Can I tell you how to object inside add properites?